# ORACLE SQL to replace/lpadd '-' (or) '_' with zero(s) depending on the length of the integer after '-' or '_'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table column in oracle db where values vary as 4123456-1-2-3, 4123456-11-2-3, 4123456-2-221-3 and also QHD-086664-3_9375 etc The requirement is to find '-' or '_' from the value and replace/padd it with zeros depending upon the length of the character/integer after '-' OR '_'. Meaning if the length of integer afer '-'OR  '_' is 1 then padd 6 zeros and if the length of integer after '-' OR '_' is 2 then padd 4 zeros to it.

```
4123456-1-2-3     -> 4123456000000100000020000003
4123456-11-2-3    -> 4123456000001100000020000003
4123456-2-221-3   -> 4123456000000200002210000003
QHD-086664-3_9375 -> QHD0086664000000300009375
```

Comment: I am using the below query select (regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 1) || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 2), 6, '0') || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 3), 6, '0') || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 4), 6, '0')
       )  ;     ...... But i also need to include Underscore '_' in the match criteria along with '-'.

Comment: Then just use `[^-_]` everywhere instead of `[^-]`?

Comment: Do you always have 4 "blocks" to pad; that is, is it possible to have a string like '4123456-1-2-3-4' or '4123456-1-2'?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way - it should work pretty fast, since I didn't use any regular expression functions.

```
with
  sample_data(str) as (
    select '4123456-1-2-3'     from dual union all
    select '4123456-11-2-3'    from dual union all
    select '4123456-2-221-3'   from dual union all
    select 'QHD-086664-3_9375' from dual
  )
-- select * from sample_data; /*
, prep(str, modif) as (
    select str, translate(str, '_', '-')
    from   sample_data
  )
-- select * from prep; /*
, augm(str, modif, pos1, pos2, pos3) as (
    select str, modif, instr(modif, '-', 1, 1),
           instr(modif, '-', 1, 2), instr(modif, '-', 1, 3)
    from   prep
  )
-- select * from augm; /*
select str,
       substr(modif, 1, pos1 - 1) ||
       lpad(substr(modif, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1), 7, '0') ||
       lpad(substr(modif, pos2 + 1, pos3 - pos2 - 1), 7, '0') ||
       lpad(substr(modif, pos3 + 1)                 , 7, '0')    as new_str
from   augm;

STR               NEW_STR                               
----------------- --------------------------------------
4123456-1-2-3     4123456000000100000020000003          
4123456-11-2-3    4123456000001100000020000003          
4123456-2-221-3   4123456000000200002210000003          
QHD-086664-3_9375 QHD008666400000030009375
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is the use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with `'[^-_]+'` parameter:

```
SELECT (   REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 1)
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 2), 6, '0')
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 3), 6, '0')
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 4), 6, '0'))
  FROM your_table;
```

On your data example:

```
WITH data_example AS (
SELECT '4123456-1-2-3' AS val FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '4123456-11-2-3' AS val FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '4123456-2-221-3' AS val FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'QHD-086664-3_9375' AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT val,
       (   REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 1)
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 2), 6, '0')
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 3), 6, '0')
        || LPAD (REGEXP_SUBSTR (val, '[^-_]+', 1, 4), 6, '0')) AS new_val
  FROM data_example;


|  val                |  id                        | 
----------------------------------------------------
|  4123456-1-2-3      |  4123456000001000002000003 |
|  4123456-11-2-3     |  4123456000011000002000003 |
|  4123456-2-221-3    |  4123456000002000221000003 |
|  QHD-086664-3_9375  |  QHD086664000003009375     |
```

I hope I helped!